# Cannot find module '/React/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js'

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, cloud, react-scripts, react-refresh

I got the below error when deploying the code in cloud in local (windows) its working normally. When deploying in cloud I am getting following error:

** Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/React/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js'**

I tried deleting node modules and package-lock.Json file and  **running npm intall -f **
Still receiving same error.
When i checked ** npm ls react-refresh** it showed

```
├─┬ @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.11
│ └── react-refresh@0.14.0
├─┬ react-native-render-html@6.3.4
│ └─┬ react-native@0.73.1
│   ├─┬ @react-native/community-cli-plugin@0.73.11
│   │ └─┬ @react-native/metro-babel-transformer@0.73.12
│   │   └─┬ @react-native/babel-preset@0.74.0
│   │     └── react-refresh@0.14.0 deduped
│   └── react-refresh@0.14.0 deduped
└─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
  └── react-refresh@0.11.0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnkL6.png)

i tried npm dedupe -f
still no change
please help.

I am looking for a solution to deploy the code in google cloud but receiving error , but locally it was working normally.
I tried deleting node modules package-lock file and re installing  and npm dedupe -f still its not working.